# trying to install node.js on cpanel for integrating blockchain API, but getting permission denied error during installation

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, blockchain

trying to install node.js on cpanel for integrating blockchain API, but getting permission denied error during installation..

I am handling SSH through PUTTY, I am working on domain of godaddy..

I am using following commands to install node.js:

```
1) wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.9/node-v0.11.9.tar.gz
2) tar -xzvf  node-v0.11.9.tar.gz
3) cd node-v0.11.9
4) ./configure
5) make && make install
```

Relevant Node folders are outside of public_html of cpanel..

But getting error as follow:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/node'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I am also trying for sudo commands.. but its saying that its showing command not found.

Will you please give me idea how can i successfully install node.js on cpanel.. where i have to allocate the permissions??

Comment: do you have root permissions?

Comment: when i connect to ssh through putty.. then it demands credentials.. then i am providing root credentials.

Comment: Pretty sure shared hosting doesn't support nodejs, though I [could be wrong](https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/).